# How to programmatically align the views in a cardview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I'm adding 5 elements in my CardView (ImageView, TextView and 3 buttons). I'm trying to set the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and also adding the alignments in addRule() but somehow not getting the expected output.

This is my code:

```
    package bhadra.com.mca;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_add, button_reports, button_appointment, button_message;
    Context context;
    CardView cardview;
    ImageView imageview;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams, textparams, imageparams, 
    buttonparams, buttonparams2, buttonparams3;
    TextView textview;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        button_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_linear);
        //cardview = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.card_patientdetails);

        button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createCardView();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createCardView() {

        int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,160 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int margintop = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,30 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int imglayout = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,60 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int txtmargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,70 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int drawpad = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,5 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int cardpad = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,5 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int cardpad2 = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int radius = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,4 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int elevation = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10 , getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        cardview = new CardView(context);
        layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);
        layoutparams.setMargins(0,margintop,0,0);

        imageparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                imglayout, imglayout);
        imageparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        textparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        textparams.setMargins(0,txtmargin,0,0);
        textparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        buttonparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        buttonparams2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonparams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        buttonparams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        buttonparams3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonparams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        buttonparams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        imageview = new ImageView(context);
        imageview.setLayoutParams(imageparams);
        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_24px);

        textview = new TextView(context);
        textview.setLayoutParams(textparams);
        textview.setText(R.string.patient_name);
        textview.setTextSize(20);
        textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        button_reports = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless), null, 0);
        button_reports.setLayoutParams(buttonparams);
        button_reports.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_assessment_black_24px, 0, 0, 0);
        button_reports.setCompoundDrawablePadding(drawpad);
        button_reports.setText(R.string.upload_reports);
        button_reports.setTextSize(12);

        button_appointment = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless), null, 0);
        button_appointment.setLayoutParams(buttonparams2);
        button_appointment.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_today_black_24px, 0, 0, 0);
        button_appointment.setCompoundDrawablePadding(drawpad);
        button_appointment.setText(R.string.book_appointment);
        button_appointment.setTextSize(12);

        button_message = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Widget_AppCompat_Button_Borderless), null, 0);


  button_message.setLayoutParams(buttonparams3);
    button_message.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_message_black_24px, 0, 0, 0);
    button_message.setCompoundDrawablePadding(drawpad);
    button_message.setText(R.string.message);
    button_message.setTextSize(12);

    cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    cardview.setRadius(radius);
    cardview.setPadding(cardpad,cardpad2,cardpad, 0);
    cardview.setMaxCardElevation(elevation);
    cardview.addView(imageview);
    cardview.addView(textview);
    cardview.addView(button_reports);
    cardview.addView(button_appointment);
    cardview.addView(button_message);
    linearLayout.addView(cardview);
    }
}
```

This code is giving me the following output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0fUV.png)

Can someone please help me?